# Passing a method with an array parameter to a driver/test file?

Tags: java, arrays

purpose of this program is to determine whether or not the variable value
is found within any block of an array (the size of this array is specified by
a user.)
All I want to do is call this method in a driver file and have the user input
the size/data in each block of the array and then enter a value that the program will look for in the array.

```
public class PracticeExamQ10
{

    //method that recieves int array and int value//
    public int search(int[] data, int value)
    {
        //for loop to search the entire array for value//
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            //if data is found, return the index number of value (spot in the array)//
            if(data[i] == value)
                return i;
        }
        //returns -1 if value does not occur in the array data//
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I then have this as my driver file;

```
public class PracticeExamQ10Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        PracticeExamQ10 test = new PracticeExamQ10();
        test.search({5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 5);
    }
}
```

is this even possible or do I have to do this instead?

```
public class PracticeExamQ10Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] data = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        PracticeExamQ10 test = new PracticeExamQ10();
        test.search(data, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.search(new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much you saved my life! exam in 30 minutes haha.